# JQuery output Textbox

Tags: jquery

When I out put the value of TextBox and Textbox2 it only out puts the one value to msg and msg1? what am I missing in the value?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


TextBox value : <label id="msg"></label> TextBox value : <label id="msg1"></label>


<div style="padding:16px;">
  TextBox : <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" value=""> TextBox2 : <input type="text" id="textbox2" name="textbox2" value="">
</div>

<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button:#Get").click(function() {

    $('#msg').html($('input:textbox').val());
    $('#msg1').html($('input:textbox2').val());


  });
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Your snippet isn't working, maybe get that fixed first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(':button#Get').click(function() {
  $('#msg').html($('input#textbox').val());
  $('#msg1').html($('input#textbox2').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

TextBox value : <label id="msg"></label> TextBox value : <label id="msg1"></label>


<div style="padding:16px;">
  TextBox : <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" value=""> TextBox2 : <input type="text" id="textbox2" name="textbox2" value="">
</div>

<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get them by ID instead

```
$('#msg1').html($('#textbox2').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is your CSS selectors. Wine using basic CSS you target elements by righter their DOM name, class, id, or attribute. You can use a combination of these for better specificity.

```
$("button:#Get").click(function() {
```

This is not written correctly. You either want to target the button element or the id of the element. Since this id is the attribute of the button. You probably want to use the id selector. If you use the button you are targeting all buttons that are on the page which might not be what you want.

```
$('#msg').html($('input:textbox').val());
$('#msg1').html($('input:textbox2').val());
```

The way you are targeting the input fields is not going to work. You are selecting the input but it looks like you are also trying to grab the id also. The best way to do this would be to grab the id and then he the value.

This should work.

```
$("#Get").click(function() {

    $('#msg').html($('#textbox').val());
    $('#msg1').html($('#:textbox2').val());
```